# C - Read from keyboard (controlled by Ctrl+D)

Tags: c, linux, stdin, ctrl

I'm trying to emulate a `tail` command in C but I have a problem.

I need to read some lines from keyboard (STDIN) (I don't care how many lines). This read will be interrupted when Ctrl+d is pressed. I have done this function but it doesn't work.

```
int tail(int N)
{
    int i, j, c;
    char ** lines;
    /* Char matrix dynamic declaration */
    lines=NULL; // Char matrix declaration
    lines=malloc(N*sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
        lines[i]=malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
    }
    i=0;
    while (true){ // I tried this loop, but doesn't work
        /* This works. Lanes reading from the user's keyboard */
        if(i>=N){
            for(j=0; j<=N; j++){
                if (j<(N-1))
                    lines[j]=lines[j+1];
            }
            scanf(" %[^\n]", lines[N-1]);
        }else{
            scanf(" %[^\n]", lines[i]);
        }
        i++;
        /* ------------------------------------ */
        c=getchar(); // This doesn't work
        if(c==EOF)
        goto end;
    }
end:
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]); // Showing those lanes
        free(lines[i]); // Free memory
    }    
    free(lines);
    lines = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is about read user's keyboard lines and read ctrl+d at the same time. When I launch the function, it let me write some lines, but it doesn't detect when I press Ctrl+D. How can I do this?

## **EDIT:**

I have tried a new method to capture Ctrl+d and now my program ends, but I have some problems. Here is the new code:

```
int tail(int N)
{
    int i, j, k, c;
    char ** lines;

    lines=NULL;
    lines=malloc(N*sizeof(char *));
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){ 
        lines[i]=malloc(MAXLON * sizeof(char));
    }
    i=0;
    while (true){
        /* Read lines from keyboard. */
        if(i<N)
            scanf(" %[^\n]", lines[i]);
        else{
            for(j=0; j<N-1; j++){
                for(k=0; k<MAXLON; k++){
                    lines[j][k]=lines[j+1][k];      
                }
            }
            scanf(" %[^\n]", lines[N-1]);
        }
        /* ------------------------------------ */
        if((c=getchar())==EOF) break;
        else i++;
    }

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
        free(lines[i]);
    }
    free(lines);
    lines= NULL;

    return 0;

}
```

Right now, my program captures N lines from keyboard until I press 2 times Ctrl+d, but my problem now is: If I write 5 lines which are (with tail(3) for example, which shows the last 3 lines):

```
Line 1 
Line 2 
Line 3 
Line 4 
Line 5  
AND HERE I PRESS 2 TIMES CTRL+D
```

The function shows:

```
Line 4
Line 5
Line 5
```

Whats wrong? The function must show:

```
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: There are situations where `goto` and labels are acceptable. Using them for loops or loop control is not once of those situations. If you want to break out of a loop then use the `break` statement.

Comment: As for your problem, when you press the end-of-file keyboard sequence it usually have to be on an empty line.

Comment: Hello! I tried with a break too but it didn't work. When I wrote a line from my keyboard and I pressed enter and then Ctrl+D, function didn't finish...

Comment: Did you also press Enter *after* the Ctrl+D?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question on the subject: [Read from keyboard (controlled by Ctrl+d)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294077/read-from-keyboard-controlled-by-ctrld)?

Comment: Sure, I pressed Enter after that and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following code as a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argvp[])
{
    char buf[1024];

    while(gets(buf))
    {
        printf("Read: %s\n", buf);
    }
    if (ferror(stdin))
        puts("I/O error when reading");
    else if (feof(stdin))
        puts("End of file reached successfully");
}
```

Please note that

1. The size of input buffer `buf` should not be hard-coded
2. `gets` is deprecated and you should use something else like `fgets`
3. The END-OF-FILE is not recognized by `gets` in the middle of a line. It has to be the first line symbol. It is so on my RHEL 7.1 but might be different on your system
4. `stdin` should be replaced with your real input file descriptor

Comment: I have used your code (not the same, just something similar) to try to catch the Ctrl+d from STDIN. But now I have another error. Could you revise the main post which I have edited?

Comment: Your call to `getc() ` is not needed. Your first `Ctrl+D` ends your call to `scanf` and the second `Ctrl+D` exits the function. Since the last `scanf` is aborted, the contents of `lines[N-1]` is not changed and you will always see the last entered line twice.

Comment: And there is something what I can do to fix that?

Comment: Use `fgets` as I have suggested. And `sscanf` to process the user input. In other words, replace `printf` in my example with the body of your while loop and modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has worked so well. I appreciate your time.